# Checkboxes in Ember Js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, checkbox, handlebars.js

I have a data fixture adapter say..

```
App.Person.reopenClass({
FIXTURES: [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Name1',
    },
    {
        id:2,
        name:'Name2'
    }
]
```

});

In  my template i want to bind this model with checkboxes..like there are two names in the model so there should be two checkboxes with  name as their labels

This is my route

```
App.IndexRoute=Ember.Route.extend({
model:function(){
    return this.store.findAll('person');
}
```

});

and this is Controller-on click of a button  I want to retrieve info about the checkboxes

```
App.IndexController=Ember.ArrayController.extend({

actions:{
    buttonHandler:function(){
             //Get Names which are checked/unchecked
        }}
});
```

Is there any way to bind  the model with checkboxes and retrieve which checkboxes have been selected  in the controller?

Comment: When is this buttonHandler called? On press of a button or any of the checkboxes?

Comment: The button handler would be called on press of a button @blessenm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
App.Person.reopenClass({
 FIXTURES: [
 {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Name1',
    checked: false
 },
 {
    id:2,
    name:'Name2',
    checked: false
 }
]);
```

your template:

```
{{#each controller.model as |obj|}}
  {{input type="checkbox" name=obj.name checked=obj.checked}}
{{/each}}
<button {{action 'buttonHandler'}}>Get checked</button>
```

your controller:

```
App.IndexController=Ember.ArrayController.extend({

 actions:{
   buttonHandler:function(){
      var checked_only = this.get('model').filterBy('checked', true);
   }}
});
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: It shows error---Uncaught Error: Parse error on line 10:
...controller.model as |obj|}}  {{input ty
-----------------------^
Expecting 'CLOSE', 'CLOSE_UNESCAPED', 'STRING', 'INTEGER', 'BOOLEAN', 'ID', 'EQUALS', 'DATA', 'SEP', got 'INVALID'

Comment: Which version of Ember are you on? Maybe you should change the template into: `{{#each  obj in controller.model}}`

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using ObjectProxy like described in this blog post: http://www.poeticsystems.com/blog/ember-checkboxes-and-you

You can avoid putting a "checked" property on the model and must not take care of the serializer trying to save the checked property and so forth.

**From the blog post**

Proxy Model:

```
proxiedModel: Ember.computed.map('model', function(model) {
  return Ember.ObjectProxy.create({
    content: model,
    checked: false
  });
}
```

Template:

```
<ul>
{{#each proxiedModel}}
  <li>
    {{input type="checkbox" value=checked}}
    {{name}}
  </li>
{{/each}}
</ul>
```